Check if time between times
I'm trying to run this query that check if the current time not between 19:00:00 and 02:00:00 (next day)
if (select convert(nvarchar (8), getdate(), 114)) not between '19:00:00' and '02:00:00' 
begin 
    print 'a' 
end

It's not working when the time is after 00:00:00
Why?

You can work around the problem by combining 2 conditions. One to exclude the the hours before midnight and another to exclude the hours after midnight.
IF NOT 
(
  (select convert(nvarchar (8),getdate(),114)) between '00:00:00' and '02:00:00'  
  OR 
  (select convert(nvarchar (8),getdate(),114)) between '19:00:00' and '23:59:59.999' 
)
   print 'a'


A good answer includes an explanation

You really don't want to do these kinds of tests with strings formats as you attempted to do. OP's attempt fails to work between midnight and 2am because it's doing a comparison with character data and nothing can come after '1' but before '0'
Also it's best to clearly define what happens at the boundaries. The conditionals below will assume that the instant of 02:00am should pass the test as a non-excluded time. The first two do tests use time types for comparison. The second pair extract the hour component and test against that (but these do rely on neat hourly boundaries in the first place):
-- comparison via time types
not (cast(getdate() as time) >= '19:00' or cast(getdate() as time) < '02:00')
cast(getdate() as time) >= '02:00' and cast(getdate() as time) < '19:00'

-- hour of day logic
datepart(hour, getdate()) between 2 and 18 -- includes the entire 18th hour
datepart(hour, dateadd(hour, -2, getdate())) < 17


You can't apply conditions like this with a 24-hour format. Instead, you can achieve the same thing as this
if (select convert(nvarchar (8), getdate(), 114)) between '02:00:00' and '19:00:00' 
begin 
    print 'a' 
end


Split it into 2 IFs
IF (select convert(nvarchar (8),getdate(),114)) between '00:00:00' and '02:00:00' 
  BEGIN 
   noop1:
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF (select convert(nvarchar (8),getdate(),114)) not between '19:00:00' and '23:59:59' 
    BEGIN
       print 'a' 
    END
  END

fiddle

Can you not make your 2 dates first?
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME

SET @D1 = ... today at 19:00
SET @D2 = ... tomorrow at 02:00

-- Then use
if (select getdate() not between @D1 and @D2)
begin 
    print 'a' 
end

